# What's the command to open a project file and navigate to certain coordinates?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to run a command line which opens QGIS, loads a particular project file and navigates to a set of coordinates?

If so then how would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes according to qgis --help you can:

```
qgis --project *YourProjectFile* --extent xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
```

It should do what you require.
Cheers,